# Laravel Homestead.yaml init.sh issue

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am using the Laravel Homestead installation docs. 
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead
When it says to use bash init.sh command to create the Homestead.yaml configuration file I am asked if I want to ***overwrite*** /Users/oliverwilliams/.homestead/Homestead.yaml

I thought it should be creating a new file as I can't see a current Homestead.yam file?

Answer (score 0):

Files and directories starting with a `.` are 'hidden' on Unix-like systems such as OS X. That means the file probably already exists.

You could run the following command in your terminal to see whether the file exists in the directory:
`ls -a /Users/oliverwilliams/.homestead`

You can read how to show hidden files on OS X here: http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-mac/